# How to download multiple UFT scripts from Quality Center to UFT?

Tags: hp-uft, hp-quality-center

I am able to get a single project from Quality Center at a single point in time. but i want to download multiple projects at once. is that possible and how?

thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible in ALM.